# @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) not working in Threading

Tags: multithreading, spring-mvc, annotations, transactional

I have created manual transaction it works but when using transaction annotation it fails by giving below error

**Error :**

- could not initialize proxy - no Session
- org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

**Error**

> com.krawler.common.service.ServiceException: system failure: getJournalEntryJson : could not initialize proxy - no Session
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session

**Code structure**

```
Controller Class {
    ModelAndView
    export {
        thread call(JounralExport)
    }
}
JounralExport {
    void run() {
        Function1();
        Function2();
        Function3();
    }
    Function1() {
        manual transaction create commit;
    }
    Function2() {
        FucntionA();
    }
    Function3() {
        manual transaction create commit;
    }
}
Class B {
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED) private JounralExport entry;
    setter FuncitonA() {
            obj.put("companyname", entry.getCompany().getCompanyName()); // error could not initialize proxy - no Session 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Always format your code so that it's readable and not just dump everything on one line

Comment: The actual code matters. Post actual code, not pseudo-code. The actual exception stack trace matters, too. Posst the actual exception stack trace.